# Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable is not setting the variable value

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created a release pipeline using the 'classic' method instead of YAML.

A variable, ReleasePipelineRunTime, has been declared with the value 'Updated in the pipeline'.

I've added a v2 PowerShell task to run the following in-line script

```
$now=$(Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmm");
"now: $now"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ReleasePipelineRunTime]$now"
"ReleasePipelineRunTime: $(ReleasePipelineRunTime)"
```

The variable is not being set and the logged output is

```
2023-10-24T08:05:00.2706627Z ##[section]Starting: Set variables
2023-10-24T08:05:00.3055374Z ==============================================================================
2023-10-24T08:05:00.3056063Z Task         : PowerShell
2023-10-24T08:05:00.3056356Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
2023-10-24T08:05:00.3056581Z Version      : 2.180.1
2023-10-24T08:05:00.3056844Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-10-24T08:05:00.3057137Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
2023-10-24T08:05:00.3057368Z ==============================================================================
2023-10-24T08:05:02.2667659Z Generating script.
2023-10-24T08:05:02.2676359Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2023-10-24T08:05:02.2692790Z ##[command]"C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\ADOAgents\Prod\_work\_temp\1c1aa42b-ddf5-4e0b-955d-b4101a84fa2d.ps1'"
2023-10-24T08:05:02.2696432Z now: 202310240905
2023-10-24T08:05:02.2714701Z ReleasePipelineRunTime: Updated in pipeline
2023-10-24T08:05:02.2855986Z ##[section]Finishing: Set variables
```

Firstly, why is the value of ReleasePipelineRunTime still 'Updated in the pipeline' and not '202310240905'?

Secondly, I've looked at the list of defined variables but there doesn't appear to be one that stores the time the release pipeline runs which seems odd. OIs there one that I haven't spotted?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `task.setvariable` does not update in the same step because it updates an environment variable. You have to read your variable in the next step.

```
Step1:
  $now=$(Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmm");
  "now: $now"
  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ReleasePipelineRunTime]$now"

Step2:
  "ReleasePipelineRunTime: $(ReleasePipelineRunTime)"
```

Comment: Hello Shamrai, Thanks for this. I added a further powershell task to follow that I described above and as you said the variable was indeed set so thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

As @Shamrai mentions, and regarding to Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax)

> In this example, you can see that the template expression still has
> the initial value of the variable after the variable is updated. The
> value of the macro syntax variable updates. The template expression
> value doesn't change because all template expression variables get
> processed at compile time before tasks run. In contrast, macro syntax
> variables evaluate before each task runs.

Here is the example from Microsoft doc, if we run it:

```
variables:
- name: one
  value: initialValue 

steps:
  - script: |
      echo ${{ variables.one }} # outputs initialValue
      echo $(one)
    displayName: First variable pass
  - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=one]secondValue"
    displayName: Set new variable value
  - script: |
      echo ${{ variables.one }} # outputs initialValue
      echo $(one) # outputs secondValue
    displayName: Second variable pass
```

We will see in the first step, the variable is equal:

[image]

But at the second step, it contains the new value:

[image]

Comment: Hello Maytham, Thanks for this. I added a further powershell task to follow that I described above and as you said the variable was indeed set so thank you for this.